# Error with DOCplex CP objective function expression

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, docplex

I am trying to replicate a CPLEX ILOG objective function in DOcplex but keep running into some errors. I am not too sure on how the type_of_next function() works with indexing, making it difficult for me to debug the code.

**CPLEX ILOG CODE:**
dexpr int totDistance =
(sum(j in Jobs, v in Vehicles) Dist[j.id][typeOfNext(seqVeh[v], itvJ2V[j][v], j.id, j.id)]) ;

**DOcplex CODE:**
totDistance = DARP_cp.sum(distance_matrix[i][DARP_cp.type_of_next(x[k], zeta[(i,k)], i, i)]
for i in range(nrows) for k in range(1, no_vehicles + 1))
**Error Message:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\bsraf3\OneDrive - Loughborough University\CPLEX TUTORIALS\DOcplex Tutorials\DARP\DARP_CP.py", line 115, in 
for i in range(nrows) for k in range(1, no_vehicles + 1))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docplex\cp\modeler.py", line 567, in sum_of
arr = build_cpo_expr(x)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docplex\cp\expression.py", line 2390, in build_cpo_expr
return build_cpo_expr_array(val)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docplex\cp\expression.py", line 2420, in build_cpo_expr_array
cpval = _CPO_VALUES_FROM_PYTHON.get_or_create('array', val, normalize_value, _create_cpo_array_expr)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docplex\cp\expression.py", line 2300, in get_or_create
kval = kbldr(pexpr)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docplex\cp\expression.py", line 2409, in normalize_value
return _CacheKeyTuple(val)

File "C:\Users\bsraf3\OneDrive - Loughborough University\CPLEX TUTORIALS\DOcplex Tutorials\DARP\DARP_CP.py", line 115, in 
for i in range(nrows) for k in range(1, no_vehicles + 1))

**IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices**

The idea was to have an objective function expression which could later be added to the model.
that is:** DARP_cp.add(DARP_cp.minimize(totDistance))**

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to put a decision expression into "[]" in Python.

Try to use "[element](https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/cp/docplex.cp.modeler.py.html?highlight=type_of_next#docplex.cp.modeler.type_of_next)" instead.

Maybe something like that:

```
DARP_cp.sum(element(DARP_cp.type_of_next(x[k], zeta[(i,k)], i, i), distance_matrix[i]) for i in range(nrows) for k in range(1, no_vehicles + 1))
```

I hope this helps